# OpenCV GpuMat multiply complex matrices element-wise

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Currently, I am multiplying two complex matrices element-wise using OpenCV, I want to do this on a GPU using cuda.

```
cv::Mat complexMultiplication(cv::Mat a, cv::Mat b)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> pa;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> pb;
    cv::split(a, pa);
    cv::split(b, pb);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> pres;
    pres.push_back(pa[0].mul(pb[0]) - pa[1].mul(pb[1]));
    pres.push_back(pa[0].mul(pb[1]) + pa[1].mul(pb[0]));

    cv::Mat res;
    cv::merge(pres, res);

    return res;
}
```

I thought that I had found a similar function in the opencv cuda documentation `mulSpetrums`, this however is not what I intended to do. My goal is element-wise multiplication.

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat complexMultiplication(cv::cuda::GpuMat a, cv::cuda::GpuMat b)
{
    cv::cuda::GpuMat res;
    cv::cuda::mulSpectrums(a, b, res, 0);

    return res;
}
```

I ended up using the following, but I am still looking for more efficient methods.

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat complexMultiplication(cv::cuda::GpuMat a, cv::cuda::GpuMat b)
{
    std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> pa;
    std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> pb;
    cv::cuda::split(a, pa);
    cv::cuda::split(b, pb);

    cv::cuda::GpuMat pa0pb0, pa0pb1, pa1pb0, pa1pb1, real, complex, res;

    cv::cuda::multiply(pa[0], pb[0], pa0pb0);
    cv::cuda::multiply(pa[0], pb[1], pa0pb1);
    cv::cuda::multiply(pa[1], pb[0], pa1pb0);
    cv::cuda::multiply(pa[1], pb[1], pa1pb1);

    cv::cuda::subtract(pa0pb0, pa1pb1, real);
    cv::cuda::add(pa0pb1, pa1pb1, complex);

    cv::cuda::merge({real, complex}, res);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I am unaware of matrix division other than multiplying by an inverted matrix. Could you demonstrate manually with simple/small matrices what you mean? Please discuss the fact that non-invertible matrices exist.

Comment: @Yunnosch I updated my question, I will also try to use matrix inversion. Thx :)

Comment: Your `complexMultiplication()` is not matrix multiplication at all, `mulSpectrums()` is element-wise multiplication. Inverting the matrix won't get you what you want.

Comment: I might have mistaken your meaning. Referring to Ivellas contrubution, consider whether what you want is element-wise division. Feel free to point out my misunderstanding (maybe try to prevent it for others by rephrasing your question).

Comment: @Yunnosch I have edited my question, is it more clear like this? Sorry for the unclarity.

Comment: The definitions you gave are for element-wise multiplication and element-wise division, which is very different from "[matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)" as commonly understood in mathematics. So, the wording is still a bit off.

Comment: @Ivella how should I define the functionality in the first given function `complexMultiplication()` to be more accurate?

Comment: I very much like the expression "element-wise". If you can agree that it describes your goal, then I propose to use that expression in the question. Reading it would have prevented my "matrix division" misunderstanding. I seem to be thinking along the "mathematics" way Ivella mentions. Reading your "should work like this", also contains enough info to be clear - just not "obvious" or "convenient".

Comment: The conventional mathematical description is [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) or Schur product depending on whether your prefer French or German mathemtical etymology